# Filter an embeded list in mongo DB with buildr in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a problem in writing my query with C#.
Hee is my data model:

```
    public class SpamEntity:MongoEntity
{
    public IList<MessageData> MessageData { get; set; }

}

public class MessageData
{

    public IList<string> EmbeddedLinks { get; set; }


}
```

here I have a list of links like :

```
var myLinks = {"a.com", "b.com", "c.com"}
```

I want to filter those documents that their list of EmbededLinks is not empty (count or length is zero) and exactly the same as myLinks.
I am halfway and I do not know what to do in continue.
my filter is something like:

```
            var filter =
                Builders<SpamEntity>.Filter.ElemMatch(s => s.MessageData,
                    s => s.EmbeddedLinks != null  && s.EmbededLinks == ???);
```

I think the below should not be correct.

```
s.EmbededLinks == myLinks
```

and also I can not use count:
`s.EmbeddedLinks.count` => It does not work

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about mongodb specific filters..
below is a linq variant  (assumption ordering doesnt matter!)

```
var filtered =
            spamEntities.MessageData.Where(
                m =>
                m.EmbeddedLinks.Any() && //ensure EmbeddedLinks has some values
                m.EmbeddedLinks.Count() == myLinks.Count() && //and that count is same as our reference collection
                m.EmbeddedLinks.Intersect(myLinks).Count() == myLinks.Count()); //ensure elements match
```

working code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Xunit;

 namespace SOProject
{
public class SpamEntity
{
    public IList<MessageData> MessageData { get; set; }

}
public class MessageData
{
    public IList<string> EmbeddedLinks { get; set; }

}
public class SO
{
    [Fact]
    public void Q_63081601()
    {
        var myLinks = new List<string> { "a.com", "b.com", "c.com" };
        var size = myLinks.Count();

        var data2 = new List<string>(myLinks);
        var data3 = new List<string>(myLinks) { "sdsadsad.com" };
        var data4 = new List<string> { "c.com", "b.com", "a.com" };

        var spamEntities = new SpamEntity()
        {
            MessageData = new List<MessageData>
            {
                new MessageData()
                {
                    EmbeddedLinks = new List<string> { "", "aaaa.com", "bbb.com" }
                },
                new MessageData()
                {
                    EmbeddedLinks = data2
                },
                new MessageData
                {
                    EmbeddedLinks = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToList()
                },
                new MessageData()
                {
                    EmbeddedLinks = data2
                },
                new MessageData()
                {
                    EmbeddedLinks = data3
                },
                new MessageData()
                {
                    EmbeddedLinks = data4
                }
            }
        };

        var filtered =
            spamEntities.MessageData.Where(
                m =>
                m.EmbeddedLinks.Any() && //ensure EmbeddedLinks has some values
                m.EmbeddedLinks.Count() == myLinks.Count() && //and that count is same as our reference collection
                m.EmbeddedLinks.Intersect(myLinks).Count() == myLinks.Count()); //ensure elements match
        Assert.True(filtered.Any());
        Assert.Equal(3, filtered.Count());
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I can do with LINQ. I'm stuck on using filters.

Comment: ok, good luck I have no experience WRT.. I hope mongodb client libs have some sort of linq expression support  :)